# Submitted data in HTML form does not display

Tags: php, html, forms

Can someone tell my why the data I submit in my HTML form does not display? I am using HTML and PHP. BTW My server is running (APACHE)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title>My PHP Project</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="form.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>

 //PHP code:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What output do you get, when you do what?  Are the above two separate files?

Comment: Make sure that the name of the file containing php code is "form.php"

Comment: 1.action not needed if it needs to be on the same page

2.Page need to be save as .php not .html

3.Check that actual data is coming or not using `isset()` and then try to print it out

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use body and html tag twice in the same page. On page referesh data won't show because it will on show once form submit so use `isset()` and try following

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title>My PHP Project</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="form.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ ?>
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
<?php }?>

</body>
</html>
```

Also you need to make sure that this file name is `form.php` because action attribute is targeting `form.php` file

Answer (score 1):

You must have two seperate files one is the index.html view  and form.php

In your **index file**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title>My PHP Project</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="form.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Then in your second file **form.php**

```
 //PHP code:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```